# deployment angular 15 project on nginx got server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, mime-types, mime

I am deploying angular app to domain via nginx server with docker file and my deployment angular path is /domain/ui/ but thing is that after deployment i got above error.

```
**> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
> the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type
> checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec**
```

index.html after deployment on DEV

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ISA</title>
  <base href="/ui/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>
```

I have below solutions but none of worked:

1. tsconfig.json's target is **es2015**
2. change dist/ui to dist only
3. add  below in nginx.conf file

> ```
>   types {
>       module js;
>     }
>     include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
> ```

I am sharing my nginx.conf,dockerfile file:

1. docker file:

```js
FROM artifactorycloud.ual.com/v-docker/node:16 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --max-old-space-size=4096
COPY . .
RUN npm run build -- --base-href /ui/ --configuration=development

FROM artifactorycloud.ual.com/v-docker/nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the nginx conf that we created to the container
COPY ./nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

2. nginx.conf:

```js
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         6;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         1000;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers            16 8k;
    client_max_body_size    256M;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /ui/health/ {
        rewrite ^/ui/health/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /ui/health/index.html;
    }
    location /ui/ {
        rewrite ^/ui/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /ui/index.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue fixed for me my app is deployed inside parent folder- /ui/health/ i forgot that path inside location tag:

```
location /ui/health/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /ui/health/index.html;
}
```